# How to edit TextInput by pressing its container in expo react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to be able to edit or "enter" the text input field by touching its parent container instead of just the input because the input is kind of small. Is this possible? I thought about wrapping it in `TouchableOpacity` but im unsure how to link it to the text input.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {console.log(''}}>
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Text> Protein</Text>
    <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(event) => setItem(prevState => ({ ...prevState, proteins: parseInt(event) }))}
        keyboardType={'numeric'}
        value={item.proteins}
        placeholder='0'
    />
</View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a reference with `useRef` hook `const textInput = useRef(null)`

```
<Pressable style={styles.container} onPress={() => textInput?.current?.focus()}>

    <Text> Calories</Text>
    <TextInput
        ref={textInput}
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(event) => setItem(prevState => ({ ...prevState, calories: parseInt(event) }))}
        keyboardType={'numeric'}
        value={item.calories}
        placeholder='0'
    />
</Pressable>
```